# Search for all elements in an arraylist having a particular string

Tags: java, arraylist

I am having an arraylist in which I want to retrieve all the elements matching with a particular string.
Suppose my arraylist contains  names and I want to print all the names having 'as' in it. I am using java.

Comment: I just used .contans method but as its return type is boolean , so it will print either true or false. But i want to print those elements of arraylist. i don't have any clue how to print it

Answer (score 0):

Just check inside each occurrence of the `ArrayList<String>`:

```
ArrayList<String> yourList = // fill your list here
String pattern = "as";

for (String s : yourList) {
    if (s.contains(pattern)) {
        // the string contains the pattern
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

If your pattern is not case sensitive just combine `contains()` with `toLowerCase()`

```
if (s.toLowerCase().contains(pattern.toLowerCase())) {  // ignore case
```

Comment: Edit your question and add all important info there

Comment: Commemts are not for this, if you want an answer please follow StackOverflow rules